# Prevent from choosing a folder in SWT DirectoryDialog

Tags: java, swt

I'm using the DirectoryDialog component in my application to let the user select a folder.
Now I want to have the possibility to prevent the user from choosing a specific folder. Is there a handler or listener or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done.

`DirectoryDialog` is just a thin wrapper around the native open directory dialog (for example on macOS it uses `NSOpenPanel`). The native dialog is very different on the various platforms supported by SWT making it not practical to allow this.

You could craft your own directory dialog using a `TreeViewer` and the native file APIs.